# Transformation of region

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

**Question**:-
Show that the image of the set $ S = {z \in \mathbb{C} | Im(z) \geq 0, |z|\geq 1} $ under the map
$w = u+\iota v = z+ \frac{1}{z}$ is the upper half plane of $v\geq 0$

**My approach**
Let $ z= re^{\iota \theta}$. Then $ w=re^{\iota \theta} + \frac{1}{r} e^{-\iota\theta} $
The mapping given in question is *semicircle* covering above  half of $z$ plane, and the real axis.

Therefore i have taken *three* regions for mapping onto $w-plane$

**case-1**$$ z= x, x\geq1$$
**Case-2**$$z= -x, x\geq 1$$
**Case-3** *points on boundry of surface* of the semi circle.

I understand the first two cases, but don't have any approch to third one.
hints are highly appreciated

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points on the semicircle are of the form $e^{i\theta}$ with $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$. For $z=e^{i\theta}$ we have $z+\frac 1 z = e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=2\cos\, \theta$ and $\cos\, \theta$ takes all values between $-1$ and $+1$ so the image of the semicircle is the interval $[-2,2]$ of the real axis.